# TV Satellite receiver not connecting to WiFi

Tags: router, tv, wifi-configuration, satellite

I have a satellite receiver to which I have connected a USB WiFi antenna into one of the ports and it works and picks up nearby WiFi networks. The problem is that whenever I try to connect to my own WiFi, it just doesn't work. However, when I try connecting to my phone's hotspot, it works just fine. Why can't I connect to my main router? Why does it not connect to my router but connects to my phone's hotspot? Ask for details as necessary.

Comment: Please Edit the Question with the precise make/model of the satellite receiver , USB wifi antenna, and wifi router.  If you have any logs, please post them.  If you don't have any logs, find out how to get them, and post them.  The individual manufacturers might be useful for support if you can find an error (from logs).  Please also include in your answer what version of Wifi is being used ( b g n or ac ; in the future, numbered versions will be used ) by each device.  If your hotspot only gives out g and n , but your USB antenna only works with b , then you're out of luck.

Comment: Well the model of the receiver is obscure--it's called STARTRAK ze. 7000. There is literally nothing written on the antenna either and it didn't come in a box. The router is called Tenda N301. I don't think I can get any logs from the receiver. I think I'm using network mode as 11b/g/n.

Comment: Also when I try to connect the receiver to the WiFi network, the router does not register the receiver as a connected device.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your home Wifi is 5Ghz while the satellite receiver only supports 2.4Ghz.  If your home Wifi router is dual-band, you might see two Wifi routers - you may need to select the other one.

Comment: This, or the satellite receiver is so old it doesnt support the WiFi protocol (or the router is set not to enable older protocols)